# How to describe model of mobx-state-tree with interface of typescript?

Tags: typescript, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I have some interfaces already, and I want to describe models with this interfaces, just like the code below. Otherwise I have to write again by using `types` of `mobx-state-tree`.  But this is not the right way, what is the valid solution ?

```
    import { types } from 'mobx-state-tree';

    export interface IPeople {
      name: string;
      age: number;
    }

    const Peoples = types
      .model({
        name: 'peoples',
        nancy: IPeople, // error at this line
      })

    export default Peoples;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's no way to go from a TypeScript type declaration to a `mobx-state-tree` model definition (except maybe via metadata reflection, though I doubt anyone has implemented that).  However, if you write the `mobx-state-tree` model definition, then you can generate the TypeScript type from it; see [Using a MST type at design time](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/tips/typescript#using-a-mst-type-at-design-time) in the readme.  So you would have to convert your existing interfaces, but at least you wouldn't have to keep maintaining two copies of the same information.

```
import { types, Instance } from 'mobx-state-tree';

const Person = types.model({
  name: types.string,
  age: types.number
});
export type IPeople = Instance<typeof Person>;

const Peoples = types
  .model({
    name: 'peoples',
    nancy: Person
  })

export default Peoples;
```

Comment: How would you hide private members from the interface generated with help of Instance?

Comment: May be you can try `SnapshotOut<typeof Person>`.

Comment: @马邦德 then you will have all of your references unresolved

Comment: random extra note if you have a factory function returning a state model e.g. function generatePerson() { types.model({ name: 'person' }) }   then you can get the state model with ReturnType<typeof generatePerson>  (and then Instance<ReturnType<typeof generatePerson>> for an instance of that model)